# How can I change the edit button into save button and add cancel button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want it where the edit button appears and then when I clear the edit button, the 'edit' will change into 'save' and then the 'cancel' button will also be shown.

```js
$('#edit').click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $('#save, #cancel').show();
});

$('#cancel').click(function() {
  $('#edit').show();
  $('#save, #cancel').hide();
});
```

```css
.save,
.cancel {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" value="edit">Edit</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="save">Save Changes</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" value="cancel">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The `button` elements are missing the relevant `class` and `id` attributes used in your CSS and JS respectively. Once you do that your code works as-is: https://jsfiddle.net/u8vrp47w/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please include **id** attribute in buttons

```
<form>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" value="edit" id="edit">Edit</button>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="save" id="save">Save Changes</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" value="cancel" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

and in **css** use id selection

```
<style>
    #save,
    #cancel {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

You did small mistakes in your code.

- .save, .cancel it should be added in relevant field
- add id for each button, because you used "id" selector for jQuery

```js
$('#edit').click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $('#save, #cancel').show();
 });

 $('#cancel').click(function() {
  $('#edit').show();
  $('#save, #cancel').hide();
 });
 
 $('#save').click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $('#cancel').hide();
  $('#edit').show();
 });
```

```css
button.save, button.cancel {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" value="edit" id="edit">Edit</button>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success save" value="save" id="save" >Save Changes</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary cancel" value="cancel" id="cancel" >Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

**please change value to id**

```html
<form>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="edit">Edit</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="save">Save Changes</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve in below manner. In your code Id's are missing which  are used for event triggering

```js
  $("#cancel,#save").hide()
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#edit").on("click", function() {
    $("#cancel,#save").show();
    $("#edit").hide()
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" value="edit" id="edit">Edit</button>
  <button type="save" class="btn btn-success" value="" id="save">Save Changes</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" value="cancel" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Its my pleasure.If it work for you then please mark it as accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

You are using id in your js code but this you not impliment in your button your code allmost right. use id in html which in your js

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#edit').on('click',function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $('#save, #cancel').show();
});

$('#cancel').on('click',function() {
  $('#edit').show();
  $('#save, #cancel').hide();
});
  })
```

```css
 .save,
.cancel {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="edit" value="edit">Edit</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success save" id="save" value="save">Save Changes</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary cancel" id="cancel" value="cancel">Cancel</button>
</form>
```